# Set blendlevel of object for fade isn't smooth with iPad Retina in Livecode

Tags: livecode

I create 6 images of my stack and set blendlevel of each image to 0. I input this code into stack:

```
on preopenstack
   set the fullscreenmode of this stack to "exactFit"
   if environment() is "mobile" then
      set the acceleratedRendering of this stack to true
   else
      set the acceleratedRendering of this stack to false
   end if
end preopenstack

on openstack
   if the platform contains "iphone" then
      set the compositorType of this stack to "Static OpenGL"
   end if
end openstack
```

And I input this code into my card:

```
on fadeControl nImg,bLV
    lock screen
    set the blendLevel of img nImg to bLV
    subtract 5 from bLV
    if bLV > 0 then
        send "fadeControl" && (nImg) & "," & bLV & ",5" to me in 0 milliseconds
    else
        send "fadeControl" && (nImg+1) & "," & bLV & ",5" to me in 0 milliseconds
    end if
    unlock screen
end fadeControl
```

When I test on desktop is smooth. But when I test on iPad Retina isn't smooth.

How do I solve this problem? My livecode version is 6.6.2(Stable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a visual effect instead.

```
on fadeControl nImg
   lock screen for visual effect in rect (the rect of img nImg)
   hide img nImg
   unlock screen with visual effect dissolve very fast
end fadeControl
```

Comment: Yes, this should work equally well in the desktop environment, but in testing it I see that it is simply hiding the image with no visual effect. If you remove the 'in rect…' clause on the lock screen line it works. It also works if you remove the speed modifier 'very fast' on the unlock screen line.